# Bootstrap 6 - 4 - 2 - 1 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I used bootstrap to make a responsive design on a very simple site http://www.auto-moto-klub.cz/ I spent several hours trying to achieve rouhly such behaviour based on screen size (the pixels range are just example, not necessary to be exactly these):

```
<= 300px .. 1 column
>= 301px & <= 600px .. 2 columns
>= 601px & <= 1024 .. 4 columns
>= 1024px .. 6 columns
```

Currently it works with class="col-sm-2" like this:

```
<= 767px .. 1 column .. TOO BIG around 300-767px, LOOKS CRAZY 
>= 768px .. 6 colums .. TOO SMALL around 768-1024px
```

I tried class="col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-lg-6" .. I thought it means on extra small screen size it wil have 1 column, on small 2, on medium 4 and on large 6. But probably I does's not understant it at all, because it makes strange things:

```
>= 1200px .. 2 columns
<= 1199px & >= 992px .. 3 columns
<= 991px & >= 768px .. 6 columns
<= 767px .. 6 columns somehow broken placed on the left
```

Please help. Thank you in advance for any advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following: class = "col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12". It should fix the issue.